# Number of solutions to linear diophantine equation in 3 variables

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, generating-functions

Find the number of ordered tuples $(x,y,z)$ such that $x,y,z$ are positive integers that satisfy the equation $14x+6y+21z=504$.

My first thought was generating function. Let 
$$f(z)=(z^{14}+z^{28}+z^{42}+\cdots)(z^6+z^{12}+z^{18}+\cdots)(z^{21}+z^{42}+z^{63}+\cdots)$$ $$=\frac{z^{14}}{1-z^{14}}\cdot \frac{z^{6}}{1-z^{6}}\cdot \frac{z^{21}}{1-z^{21}},$$
then the number of solutions to the desired equation is the coefficient of $z^{504}$ of $f(z)$, or coefficient of $z^{463}$ of 
$$\frac{1}{1-z^{14}}\cdot \frac{1}{1-z^{6}}\cdot \frac{1}{1-z^{21}},$$
which incidentally happens to be a prime number. But decomposing the function into partial fractions would to unpractical, I don't know if there is an easy way to find coefficient of a prime power.

After attacking the problem with generating functions in failure, I tried to look at the numbers $6=2\cdot 3,14=2\cdot 7, 21=3\cdot 7$ and notice a cyclic structure here but don't know if that's relevant.

Comment: Hint : The general solution in positive integers is $$(36-3s-3t/7s/2t)$$ with positive integers $s,t$ such that $s+t< 12$. Hence we have $$\sum_{j=1}^{10} j=55$$ triples doing the job.

Answer (score 1):

solving for $y$ we get
$$y=84-4z-2x+\frac{3z-2x}{6}$$ substututing $$t=\frac{3z-2x}{6}$$ then $$x=2z-3t-\frac{z}{2}$$ and substituting
$$z=-2s$$ we get
$$x=-5s-3t$$
$$y=84+18s+6t$$
where $s,t$ are integers